# pyspark Drop rows in dataframe to only have X distinct values in one column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I have a dataframe with a column "Category" and it has over 12k distinct values, for sampling purposes I would like to get a small sample where there are only 1000 different values of this category column.

Before I was doing:

```
small_distinct = df.select("category").distinct().limit(1000).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
df = df.where(col("category").isin(small_distinct))
```

I know this is extremely inefficient as I'm doing a distinct of the category column and then casting it into a normal python list so I can use `isin()` filter.

Is there any "spark" way of doing this? I thought maybe something with rollingoverwindows could do the job? But I cant get to solve it

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve your code using a left_semi join:

```
small_distinct = df.select("category").distinct().limit(1000)
df = df.join(small_distinct, "category", "left_semi")
```

Using left_semi is a good way to filter a table using another table, keeping the same schema, in a efficient way.